# Clojure - inversion of control macro - Timothy Baldridge

Tags: macros, clojure, inversion-of-control, state-machine, core.async

In this [podcast on core.async at approximately 12 mins in](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2013/07/10/rich-hickey-and-core-async-podcast-episode-035), Rich Hickey refers to a macro written by Timothy Baldridge that does 'inversion of control'. That this macro rewrites code into a state machine.

Does anybody have a link to where this code is on github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is located in the [`core.async`](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) repository.

The ioc macros are defined in [the `clojure.core.async.impl.ioc-macros` namespace](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/cb990537e4dca8d5bf603cdc0028d5b884f1c427/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/ioc_macros.clj)
  and used in [the implementation of the `go` macro](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/cb990537e4dca8d5bf603cdc0028d5b884f1c427/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L336-L356).